# Runtime Error relates to Node and Ruby on Rails

Tags: node.js, ruby-on-rails, ruby, runtime-error, updates

[image]

As you can see the picture above.  I am struggling to solve the error issue relates with runtime error due to Node that I need to update it.  I did the bundle update and pushed the code.  Nothing worked, then did some research and found that I need to uncomment the mini_racer platforms: :ruby on the Gemfile.  It did not work, because it blocked me from running the live environment.  I had to comment it with # on mini_racer platform and able to running the live environment on localhost.  I did not think that mini_racer was the solution to this runtime error here.  What is possible another solution/idea that I need to try to solve the runtime error here?

I am working with ruby on rails through github for this project.  Indeed, I am a beginner and working on my way to improve my knowledge and skills in this field as well.  I will continue to seek for solution as I am waiting on your help with this issue. I added a screenshot of my Gemfile on top part of it for your convenience.

Thank you.[image]

UPDATE:
After I updated the node version.  Still receiving same runtime error.  You can see what I have done on terminal. Here is the screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Why don't you just update node? Do you use nvm?

Comment: It shows many different latest version for updating a node.  There is nvm on the terminal after I typed nvm ls and it shows the old version v7.10.0.  However, there is a long list of new and latest version of node after my current version.  Which is appropriate one to pick?  the latest version of node?

Comment: I updated the node and it did not fix the problem.  I still see the same runtime error as shown on the screenshot above.    I updated the node to version v15.8.0.  However, after the update, I still see old version with new iojs-v3.3.1 is already installed.  How do I fix this problem now?

Comment: Please check the update screenshot that I provided above.

Comment: In the same terminal session that your Rails server is running, what is the output of `node -v`?

Comment: Maybe also set the new version as default using `nvm alias default x.xx.xx` and start your rails server from a new terminal session.